# why jquery append doesn't work in phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I want to add some html to a div and use this code (in the `document.ready` function):

```
var html= "<h2>Name:"+JSONObject.name+"</h2>" 
html += "<h2>Address:" +JSONObject.address+"</h2>";  
html += "<h2>Age:" +JSONObject.age+"</h2>";  
html += "<h2>Phone No.:"+JSONObject.phone+"</h2>";  
html += "<h2>Mobile No.:"+JSONObject.MobileNo+"</h2>";
$('#locationresultholder').append(html);
```

now in the body of the html file I have:

```
<div id="locationresultholder"></div>
```

now if I start the ios simulator I don't see the HTML which I wanted to append. Anyone know how?

Comment: The font tag was deprecated in 1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should check that whether including the file of the jquery~~
the make a test for example :

```
$(function(){
alert("jquery");
})
```

you can use the firebug check the jquery file path,check the 404 error,
this is what i know,i hope it is useful for  you

Comment: Thanks, i saw in the javascript debugger that it couldn't find any json objects so it didnt go further on other jscript action.